# Remove a Predifined Filter In Odoo Search View

Tags: view, filter, odoo

I created a new search View for the res.partner in Odoo. I added my custom filters. Now i want just to delete the predefined filters in my parent search view which are (My Partners  Persons Companies  Customers Suppliers)

I tried to use xpath and hide Customers for example but it's not working.

```
<record id="view_inherit_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.partner.select.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_res_partner_filter"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Search Partner">
            <xpath expr="filter[@string='Customers']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name='invisible'>1</attribute> 
            </xpath>
            <filter string="Acheteurs" name="buyer" domain="[('isBuyer','=',1)]" help="Liste Acheteurs" />
            <filter string="Vendeurs" name="seller" domain="[('isSeller','=',1)]" help="Liste Vendeur"/>
            <filter string="Fournisseurs" name="supplier" domain="[('isSupplier','=',1)]" help="Liste Fournisseurs"/>
            <filter string="Intermediares" name="interm" domain="[('isMiddle','=',1)]" help="Liste Intermdiaires"/>
            <filter string="Backoffices" name="back" domain="[('isBackOffice','=',1)]" help="Liste BackOffice"/>
            <separator/>
            <field name="category_id" string="Tag" filter_domain="[('category_id','ilike', self)]"/>
            <field name="user_id"/>
            <field name="parent_id" domain="[('is_company','=',1)]" operator="child_of"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Use with the replace attribute on the field like <xpath expr="filter[@string='Customers']" position="replace">
            </xpath>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the answer was to put the fields to hide, alone and put the new fields between

```
<search string="Search Partner"> </search>
```

Here 's the full search view

```
<record id="view_odepo_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.partner.select.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_res_partner_filter"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <!-- Fields to Delete -->

        <filter string="Customers" name="customer" domain="[('customer','=',1)]" help="Customer Partners" position="replace"/>
        <filter string="Suppliers" name="supplier" domain="[('supplier','=',1)]" help="Supplier Partners" position="replace"/>

        <!-- Fields to Add -->

        <search string="Search Partner">
            <filter string="Vendeurs" name="seller" domain="[('isSeller','=',1)]" help="Liste Vendeur"/>
            <filter string="Fournisseurs" name="supplier" domain="[('isSupplier','=',1)]" help="Liste Fournisseurs"/>
            <filter string="Intermediares" name="interm" domain="[('isMiddle','=',1)]" help="Liste Intermdiaires"/>
            <filter string="Backoffices" name="back" domain="[('isBackOffice','=',1)]" help="Liste BackOffice"/>
        </search>

        </field>
    </record>
```